# Java parse a number in exponential notation

Tags: java

I am trying to do a conversion of a String to integer for which I get a `NumberFormatException`. The reason is pretty obvious. But I need a workaround here. Following is the sample code.

```
public class NumberFormatTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String num = "9.18E+09";
  try{
   long val = Long.valueOf(num);
  }catch(NumberFormatException ne){
   //Try to convert the value to 9180000000 here
  }
 }
}
```

I need the logic that goes in the comment section, a generic one would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: @CPerkins: I don't think it's a duplicate as this question seems to be only about the numeric question, while the linked one is about each part of the notation.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use `Double.valueOf()` and cast the result to `long`:

```
Double.valueOf("9.18E+09").longValue()
```

Comment: Nice solution.. Thank you. cant accept the answer now, have to wait for 7 more minutes. :)

Comment: Old post, but if you want to enforce exact long range (no truncation) and avoid rounding errors, use `new BigDecimal(numberString).longValueExact()`

Answer (score 14):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("9.18E+09");
long val = bd.longValue();
```

But this adds overhead, which is not needed with smaller numbers. For numbers that are representable in `long`, use Joachim Sauer's solution.

Comment: This looks very clean. Thanks!