# Java NumberformatException with CSV long converting

Tags: java, csv, timestamp, numberformatexception

I'm trying to import a CSV file into Java, but when I reach the timestamp value (for instance: 135824328205) I get the following message:

> 02-25 10:40:48.629: W/System.err(23341):
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: 1.35998E+12

I would like to store it as a long value, but it isn't works, here is my code:

```
in.setTS(Long.parseLong(dataArray[2]));
```

Can anybody help me ? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the contents of dataArray[2]?

Comment: `1.35998E+12` isn't long

Comment: @PremGenError: it isn't. but if I open the csv with notepad I see the long value in there

Comment: What is the contents of dataArray[2] and how are you getting it from the CSV file?

Comment: content of dataArray[2]  = 1360331885000 , it is an string

Comment: It looks like something is converting the plain integer value in your file, into an exponential String. You can use the answer below, to parse exponential values. Or if you're curious, track down whatever is converting your value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722122/java-parse-a-number-in-exponential-notation):

```
in.setTS(Double.valueOf(dataArray[2]).longValue());
```

in case `dataArray[2]` holds the relevant exponential notation as string

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) can also help you here.

Answer (score 0):

For huge numbers it is highly useful to use `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(dataArray[2], 10);
```

Assuming `dataArray[2]` is string

Refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)