# What is the equivalent scala code to this python code: "%i" % float(9.04E09)

Tags: scala

I am a Scala noob. I am converting a python script to Scala. In one of my routine I am reading from a CSV file. The column is in scientific notation format. My code in python is:

```
"%i" % float(line[USER_ID]) where line[USER_ID] = "9.04E09"
```

This converts to `"9040000000"`. How do I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Scala 2.10 String interpolation:

```
scala> val numString = "9.04E09"
numString: String = 9.04E09

scala> val num = numString.toFloat
num: Float = 9.04E9

scala> val formatted = f"$num%1.0f"
formatted: String = 9040000000
```

If you are not using Scala 2.10, you'll have to do the String formatting yourself, which isn't really that different:

```
scala> val formatted = format("%1.0f", num)
formatted: String = 9040000000
```

I'm also assume your data is sanitized (i.e., no validation/exception is being done, in case your input string doesn't parse to a valid float).

Comment: I should mention that I assumed you want the output to remain a String, since that's what you have in your original Python version. If you want it to be an actual numeric type, Brian and Eran's answers are probably better.

Answer (score 1):

The Java way: (see here as well [Java parse a number in exponential notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722122/java-parse-a-number-in-exponential-notation))

```
java.lang.Double.valueOf("9.04E09").longValue()
```

Another way in Scala:

```
"9.04E09".toDouble.longValue
```

Or

```
"9.04E09".toDouble.formatted("%.0f")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java API.

```
scala> val d = new java.lang.Double("9.04E09")
d: Double = 9.04E9

scala> val l = d.longValue
l: Long = 9040000000
```