# Convert double to String in Java

Tags: java, string, types, double

I am to convert a double value to a String.

```
double d=12345678.999;
String str = String.valueOf(d);
```

or, just plain

```
String str = ""+d;
```

Does it, however in the exponent form-- returning the String value:

```
1.2345678999E7
```

I need the value as is in the String:

```
12345678.999
```

Is there a way to do this? I can parse the string for the value of exponent-- the portion after 'E' and go from there, but there must be an easier way of doing this.

//===========================

EDIT:

the length of the decimal part in the input isn't known, it can be any number of digits:

```
12345678.999
```

or

```
12345678.9999999
```

Imposing a format for the decimal part would fix the number of decimal digits(?)

Comment: Use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: Try this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722122/java-parse-a-number-in-exponential-notation

Comment: Here you have a useful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use NumberFormat to format Strings so that they do not show up in scientific notation.

```
String str = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(d);
```

Comment: java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().format(0.9999999d) Generate 1

Answer (score 2):

use `String.format()`:

```
double d=12345678.999;
System.out.println(String.format("%12.3f", d));
```