# String to double issue in Java

Tags: java

I am getting a strange problem while parsing a double from String of length greater than 7.

For example: 
The String contains the value:

```
String str = '123456789'
```

When I run the following code:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
System.out.println(d);
```

The output is:

```
1.23456789E8
```

The value stored in the database is:

```
123456789.0000000000000000
```

The data type of column is decimal(40,16)

And there is no exception generated. 
Please let me know how can I handle it.

Comment: Seems ok to me (except for the wrong quotes used to define the string), where do you see a problem?

Comment: 1.23456789E8 = 1.23456789 * 10^8 = 123456789 = 123456789.0000000000000000 - 

No problem there.

Comment: The problem is that I have to display the same value on my website and over there it shows 1.23456789E8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert double to String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067808/convert-double-to-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

`1.23456789E8` is `1.23456789 x 10 ^8^`, so the result looks as it should.

Comment: Yes but I want it to be displayed as it is stored in the database.

Comment: look into things like DecimalFormat

Answer (score 2):

`1.23456789E8` is in scientfic format and can be read as `1.23456789 * Math.pow(10,8)`

To print in decimal format use:

```
System.out.printf("%f", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a differently formatted output use for example

```
System.out.printf("%15.7f%n", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "123456789";
double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
System.out.printf("%f\n", d);// print 123456789.000000
```

See also [How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, this will help you what you want.

```
new BigDecimal(d).toPlainString()
```

Comment: Thanks. The output is fine now.

Comment: This way of doing it will give you unexpected results for most non-integer values of `d`.  To get your `double` looking the same as what's in your database, using `BigDecimal`, you'd be better to write `BigDecimal.valueOf(d).toPlainString()`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I appreciate that you want to make ans better, I havent tried that approach, if you are confirm then you can edit that ans, so that other can be beneficiary from it.