# Read long integers from txt in java

Tags: java, long-integer

I have a list of long integers in a text file. I want to read those numbers to long  arraylist in java.  Out numbers are stored in the file:

```
2.2278e+08
1.2339e+09
6.1868e+08
```

My code to read those long numbers are the following:

```
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("ids.txt"))) {
                    ids.add(Long.parseLong(line, 10));
                    System.out.println(Double.valueOf(line).longValue());
}
```

However I got the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.2278e+08"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at twittertrendsetters.TwitterTrendSetters.main(TwitterTrendSetters.java:580)
```

Java Result: 1

How can I convert 2.2278e+08 to the long integer number 22278111 which is in fact

Comment: The number is stored in floating-point format. You may want to use `Double.valueOf(line)` instead. Then you can turn it into a long if you want doing `Double.longValue()` instance method.

Comment: This is called scientific notation. You may want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722122/java-parse-a-number-in-exponential-notation

Comment: System.out.println(Double.valueOf(line)); gives me the same error.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo +1 - you should answer instead of commenting in this case.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble( line ).toLong()`

Comment: @Sarvesh `parseDouble` returns a primitive double, therefore it is not an object and you cannot dereference it.

Comment: (long)Double.parseDouble("2.2278e+08")

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo You are right. I was using scala console, and forgot that part because of implicit conversion to object by Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that numbers like 2.2278e+08, 1.2339e+09 and 6.1868e+08 are in floating-point notation and therefore cannot be parsed as long numbers directly.

However you could parse them as double values doing something like

```
long l = Double.valueOf("2.2278e+08").longValue();
```

Of course this departs from the assumption that you know that all these numbers are integers and that they fit in the size of a long value. Otherwise you may need to resort to other techniques.

Comment: As a side note, `new BigDecimal("2.2278e+08").longValue()` would also work, but the result should be the same.